# Controlling particles and height in React web app for mobile devices

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-particles-js

Currently learning React so apologies!

Im creating a web app in React.js and have successfully imported React-Particles-JS which is currently as:

```
<Particles
            canvasClassName="example"
            params={{
                "particles": {
                "number": {
                "value": 200
            },
            "size": {
            "value": 3
            }
           },
            "interactivity": {
            "events": {
            "onhover": {
                "enable": true,
                "mode": "repulse"
             }
            }
            }
        }} />
```

This works fine when viewing on a larger screen, but when viewing on a mobile makes it very cluttered so, what i want to know is how to reduce the value from 200 to something smaller depending on if in a smaller screen, and also increase the height of the Particles  canvas

At the moment it currently looks like this in mobile mode:
[image]

Many Thanks!

Comment: Try upgrading the `tsparticles` dependency to 1.17.12, if this doesn’t work, try `react-tsparticles` 1.17.12, There was a retina bug reported here https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles/issues/837

Comment: this does not answer my question? i wasnt to reduce the number of particles for mobile

Comment: There was a bug with retina displays, displaying more particles than configured

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me:

```
responsive: [{
          maxWidth: 500,
          options: {
            particles: {
              number: {limit: 50},
            },
          }
        }]
```

Sorry it's not inline like yours, I did this in a component file.
Hope this helps.